# Babel transpile to ES6 for use with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, babeljs

I want to "transpile" my node 8 code to node 6.10 so it will run on AWS Lambda, and I'm following the tutorial here:

https://medium.com/@tomokazukozuma/how-to-transpile-es6-and-use-it-with-aws-lambda-78da3d7aefe3

Everything seems to work, my .babelrc looks like:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env", {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So now I run babel script -d dist
It says:

script\handler.js -> dist\handler.js

But when I take a look at dst/handler.js (Windows 10 in case it matters) the code has changed somewhat but it's clearly not going to run on Lambda, my async/awaits are all still there. How can I get code that runs on Lambda out of babel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `.babelrc` will only work if you use Node6.10 to **transpile** (not run) your Node 8 code.

Reference: [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env)

> For convenience, you can use "node": "current" to only include the necessary polyfills and transforms for the Node.js version that you use to run Babel:

To target Lambda's runtime, you should set it to `6.10` instead of `current`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.